# PHP return randomised array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a new array from an existing one with a random number of records between 2 and 10, I have this so far

```
//Select a random number
$random_number = (rand(2,10));

// Setup an array of names
$names = array("john", "joe", "simon", "peter", "paul");

// Create new array
$random_field_names = array_rand($names, $random_number);

print_r($random_field_names);
```

This gives me an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 11
)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want the desired output to be? I'm a little confused about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) explains why you don't get the names (I stress in bold):

> Picks one or more random entries out of an array, and returns **the key** (or keys) of the random entries.

You seem to want the values. That you can achieve like this:

```
 array_intersect_key($names,  array_flip(array_rand($names, $random_number)));
```

Also make sure your random number is not greater than the array size:

```
$random_number = rand(2,5);
$names = array("john", "joe", "simon", "peter", "paul");
$result = array_intersect_key($names,  array_flip(array_rand($names, $random_number)));
print_r ($result);
```

Note that the result maintains the original keys. If you want to renumber the keys to get an indexed array starting with index 0, then apply `array_values` to the result:

```
$result = array_values(array_intersect_key($names,  array_flip(array_rand($names, $random_number))));
```

Comment: When I try and extract an item from the new array using $result[1] I get no results, is this something to do with the way the new array is constructed?

Comment: Indeed, the result array maintains the original keys. See addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, makes much more sense now

Answer (score 2):

Use the key to get the value you want :

```
//Select a random number
$random_number = (rand(2,10));

// Setup an array of names
$names = array("john", "joe", "simon", "peter", "paul");

// Create new array
$random_field_names = array_rand($names, $random_number);

print_r($names[$random_field_names]);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. syntax error on line 5 - missing quote after `"simon`
2. [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns random key(s), not values
3. `rand(2,10)` won't work in all cases as there are only 5 entries in the array; from PHP docs: *Trying to pick more elements than there are in the array will result in an E_WARNING level error, and NULL will be returned.*

If you want to randomize the entire array, use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).